# How do you use the jQuery dropkick change callback?

Tags: jquery, onchange, window.open, jquery-dropkick

I've been working on this all day and I can't seem to find the answer! What I'm trying to do is take a `<select>` list and have each option be linked to a website with their value using `onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')"`. Is there any way to get this to work even using the change callback they have provided?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".select_element").dropkick({
     change:function(value,label){

 //your function code goes here
}});
```

Comment: in the function use the value with window.open

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not very straightforward and most of the first time users got stuck in this.
for now u can refer this sample code.

```
$(".CLASS_OF_SELECT_TAG").dropkick({
    change: function (value, label) {
           //Logic that you want to apply onchange event.
           //in your case some opening a window
    }
});
```

Cheers